Same models but different in output behavior for Ollama's version and Huggingface's Version
I'm working around with Ollama right now and the task I'm working on is translation.
The model I used are Qwen2-0.5B and Qwen2-1.5B. From ollama, we can access to the q4_0 quantized version of these two models. In addition, I also downloaded the same model files from huggingface, used llama.cpp to get .gguf file with the same q4_0 quantization method by myself and put it into ollama to run.
However, the output behavior is quite consistently different despite I used the same prompt and tested it multiple time. The model I quantized myself yielded some additional explanation while the model from ollama just give the output shortly following the prompt.
Here are the results
Qwen2-1.5B Q4_0 self-quantized of the left and Qwen2-1.5B Q4_0 from ollama on the right


